# What are some ways to add meta informational inputs to file upload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a jQuery call to add and remove file inputs dynamically, so that a user can add as many attachments as necessary before submitting the the form. I can add and remove attachments as necessary.

```
 //New Attachments      
    $("button#add-another-row").click(function(){
        var newRow  = "<div class='new-attachment-row'>";
            newRow += "<button class='delete-btn'>Delete </button>";
            newRow += "<input name='attachments[]' type='file' /><br />";
            newRow += " OK for Customer:<input name='okForCustomer[]' type='checkbox' /></div>";
        $("#attachments-cell").prepend(newRow);

        return false;
    });
```

[image]

Each file should have either Ok / Not Ok for Customer stored in the database which I will use to determine where this file is able to be shown to my users.

**How do I write the javascript so that the attachments array is tied to the ok/not okay array? Do I have to use a multi-dimensional arrary? What would the syntax be?**

I'm using PHP/MySQL backend to process the POST values.

Answer (score 1):

Simple option is to keep a counter var in your JS code, and use that counter as the array index in your field names:

e.g.

```
var fields_displayed = 0;

$("button#add-another-row").click(function(){
    fields_displayed++;
    var newRow  = "<div class='new-attachment-row'>";
        newRow += "<input name='attachments[" + fields_displayed + "]' type='file' /><br />";

                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---add this
```

PHP will honor your array keys, if they're valid key values. Then you can use the SAME array key in your other input fields, so that `foo[1]` matches up with `bar[1]` and `baz[1]` in the other input fields.

Comment: I thought about this but how will I know if a checkbox is not checked or not? If it's not checked it won't send through POST? I might change it to a radio buttons but same issue I need to tie those to the file.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['checkboxfield'][$i])) { ... the $i'th checkbox is checked }`. unchecked checkboxes don't submit, so there wouldn't be a corresponding key in your $_POST array